# ECSlidingviewcontroller-2 : Trying To Achieve Bounce Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

I'm using `ecslidingviewcontroller 2` and i'm trying to make a bouncy animation when open the off-canvas menu or close it ..

I know it should be in the method

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext ;
```

But i have no idea how it should be cause i have a little experience in the animation coding.